# React: Get DOM data from sibling elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(I am new to React and TypeScript so apologies ahead of time)

I am trying to build a bar that I can fill between 2 elements and I think the best way might be to figure out where those two elements are after the component is built and then do some logic in order to size the bar properly.

For reference here is what im trying to build:
[image]

How / is it possible to get the DOM using something like `getBoundingClientRect()` in order to know how big and where the bar should start and stop?

Here is the component set up so far:

```
import React from "react";
import './CardLineItem.css';
import CardLineItemImage from "./CardLineItemImage";
import { FaChevronRight } from 'react-icons/fa';
import CardLineItemProgressBar from "./CardLineItemProgressBar";

export default class CardLineItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CardLineItem">
        <CardLineItemImage cardUrl="platinum-card.png" altText="platinum-card"/>
        <FaChevronRight className="CardLineItemChevron" size="25%"/>
        <CardLineItemProgressBar />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I looked into `componentDidMount` and `this.children.toArray` but that never returns anything. Suggestions on how I could best do this? `CardLineItemProgressBar` is the element I need to be flexible depending on the browser size.

Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure what are you trying to do with the bar, but this sounds like it could be solved by css. For example setting the image and icon width and the have the bar stretch in the middle?

Comment: If you're trying to access an element maybe you can `createRef` could help you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading the size and position of the other items, and making adjustments before the DOM paints, it's much better for performance to rely on CSS to do something like this.

I would highly recommend seeing if [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) can fulfill what you're trying to do here.

By bringing the progress bar component between the two other components in the JSX tree like this ...

```
<div className="CardLineItem">
  <CardLineItemImage cardUrl="platinum-card.png" altText="platinum-card"/>
  <CardLineItemProgressBar className="CardLineItemProgress" />
  <FaChevronRight className="CardLineItemChevron" size="25%"/>
</div>
```

... you can add the flex style to the `.CardLineItem` and a `.CardLineItemProgress` class to have your progress bar grow accordingly to fill the space.

```cs
.CardLineItem {
  // ... your other styles
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}
.CardLineItemProgress {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

---

That said, if you really would prefer to add JS calculations to manually calculate and set the size, [`getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate) should be what you're looking for.

And if you ever switch to React functional components with hooks (standardized after React 16.8), then the hook you'd be looking for is [`useLayoutEffect()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)